# Ertrag und Erträgnis

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *Ertrag* und *Erträgnis*?

Im Duden und im Onlinewörterbuch meines Vertrauens wird bei *Erträgnis* auf *Ertrag* verwiesen.

Vergleiche ich jedoch zum Beispiel mit dem Wort *Ereignis*, dann ist mir klar, dass sich das Wort von *sich ereignen* ableitet, aber im Fall von *Erträgnis* erwarte ich nicht die Ableitung von *jmd./etw. ertragen*, sondern von dem kaufmännischen Ertragsbegriff.

Comment: Das *-sis*-Suffix ist nicht davon abhängig, dass ein entsprechendes Verb existiert, siehe z.B. *Wirrnis*.

Answer (score 5):

Einen Bedeutungsunterschied gibt es meiner Meinung nach nur begrenzt – die beiden Wörter bedeuten dasselbe.

Einen Unterschied gibt es bei der Verbreitung – *Erträgnis* wird eher selten benutzt, wenn, dann besonders in Süddeutschland, der Schweiz und Österreich. In der Fachsprache der Finanzwirtschaft scheint es auch vorzukommen, dort wird es mit

> Die Menge der in Geld bewerteten produzierten Waren und Leistungen (Output) einer Periode

[definiert](https://www.direktbroker.de/lexikon.php?art_id=16330437&buchstabe=e)

(Was wohl auch nichts anderes als "Ertrag" bedeutet)

*Erträgnis* wird von manchen Wörterbüchern der *gehobenen Sprache* zugeordnet.

Comment: Im Finanz- und Steuerwesen taucht *Erträgnis* vor allem in der Wortkombination **Erträgnisaufstellung** auf.

Comment: Genau, IQV und ich fragte mich, ob es das gibt, ob es korrekt ist und woher es kommt.

Comment: @romeoyankee Verstehe ich Deinen Kommentar richtig, dass es Dir konkret um die Herkunft des Wortes _Erträgnisaufstellung_ kommt und um dessen Zusammenhang zum Wort _Ertrag_ geht? Falls ja, lohnt es sich vielleicht, dies in Deiner Frage deutlicher zu formulieren.

Comment: Falls das deine Frage ist: Wenn *Ertrag* und *Erträgnis* dasselbe sind, dann sind auch *Ertragsaufstellung* und *Erträgnisaufstellung* dasselbe.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Wenn wir uns darüber einig sind, dass der Zusammenhang von Ertägnis und jmd./etw. ertragen nicht herzustellen ist, dann wüsste ich in der Tat gerne, woher das Wort Erträgnis kommt, um zu beurteilen, wie ich es zu verwenden habe. der Post von tofro war insofern hilfreich, dass mit der Zuordnung zur gehobenen Sprache das Wort schonmal exisitiert und anwendbar wäre. Durch das Wissen über die Herkunft erhoffe ich mir dann Klarheit über die richtige Anwendung.

Answer (score 0):

Der Ertrag ist der Gewinn, die Ernte von etwas wo man Zeit, Energie und/oder Geld investiert hat. Das Ertraegnis is was man zu ertragen/auszuhalten hat. 
In english Ertrag would we your bounty and Ertraegnis is what you have to endure.

Comment: Das ist das, was ich eingangs dachte. Dann ist aber wieder die Frage offen, woher der Ertägnisbericht im Kaufmännischen kommt? Wie ist das zu vereinbaren?

Comment: Die meisten Wörterbücher geben dir nicht Recht und sehen *Erträgnis* als Synonym für *Ertrag*.